# how to replace column values based on condition with row values on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate, tidy

I have dataframe with the wrong location in the spesific time, and there is another data with the new location but in interval time

My df is

```r
df1=data.frame(name=c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B"),
               loc=c("A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"),
               starttime=c(01.00,01.24,01.56,02.30,01.00,01.24,01.56,02.30),
               endtime=c(01.24,01.56,02.30,03.00,01.24,01.56,02.30,03.00))
```

And there is the updated location

```r
df2=data.frame(name=c("A","B"),loc=c("D","C"),"01-02"=c(0,6),"02-03"=c(10,0))
```

But in the interval time

The condition is, if value in column interval time (01-02 or 02-03) have a value (>0) then the loc= loc in df2

I want the following output

```r
df3=data.frame(name=c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B"),
               loc=c("A","A","A","D","D","C","C","C","A","A"),
               starttime=c(01.00,01.24,01.56,02.00,02.30,01.00,01.24,01.56,02.00,02.30),
               endtime=c(01.24,01.56,02.00,02.30,03.00,01.24,01.56,02.00,02.30,03.00))
```

df3 will be manipulate the time because in df2 only interval hour time, ex start in 01.56 to end 02.30 will be 01.56 to 02.00 and then 02.00 to 02.30 because location is different